# Lock down certain files

Tags: root, useradd

I want to be able to lock down files to be only executed and not editable unless root access is granted to the user.

I have a file called 'server.properties' and I would like to make it so that only root users can edit that file but the user who's home directory it is in could only view it and possibly edit some parts but not others.

I hope that this can be achieved. I am running CentOS 7 64 bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the owner and right of the file.

To change owner to root write `$ sudo chown root server.properties`. This will let you set different premissions for the owner than others.

To change the file premissions you'll have to use `chmod`. You can read more about it [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php), but you shuold set write and read access to the owner (root) and read access to others e.g `$ sudo chmod 644 server.properties` will let owner, root in your case, read and write the file, while all others may only read the file.

As mentioned in the commentes you should also make the file immutable to prevent users from deleting it. `$ sudo chattr +i server.properties`

Letting others write to just parts of the file is not possible.

Comment: Won't help; think about `rm server.properties; vi server.properties`.

Comment: @MadHatter, I don't get your comment? I can't see that OP saying anything about a root user not being able to delete the file?

Comment: Not a root user; the *unprivileged* user can do that, because the file is in his/her home directory.

Comment: Ohh.. sorry, my bad. Updated my answer with suggestion to make the file immutable.

Comment: OK, that'll work; downvote removed.